# Use Less Parameter in Attribute Selector

Tags: css, less

I'm using [Less Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature), which are really just recursive parameterized mixins.

I'd like to use the passed in parameter (`@counter`) in the selector definition as follows:

```css
.loop(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
    // call next iteration
    .loop((@counter - 1));    

    // code for each iteration
    &[data-size="@counter"] {
        width:  (3px * @counter);
        height: (3px * @counter);
    }
}

div {
  .loop(5); // launch the loop
}
```

If you copy and paste that into an online less compiler like [less2css](http://less2css.org/), you'll get the following:

```css
div[data-size="@counter"] {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
}
```

Whereas what I want is:

```css
div[data-size="1"] {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `"@counter"` - no, it won't work this way. Variables inside strings (as well as in other specific statements like selectors) are expanded using `@{var}` syntax (for obvious reasons)). See [Variable Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out you have to escape the variable with curly braces `{}` like this:

```css
.loop(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
    // call next iteration
    .loop((@counter - 1));    

    // code for each iteration
    &[data-size="@{counter}"] {
        width:  (3px * @counter);
        height: (3px * @counter);
    }
}

div {
  .loop(5); // launch the loop
}
```